# How to make an android app think that the device is in horizontal mode

Tags: android, android-layout

so basically i want to run some native android app in android TV, some apps just dont work in horizontal mode unless the app has a video and is in full screen, so is it possible that app thinks that it's always in horizontal, other than some apps run perfectly, navigation is good with remote (just have to tilt head to use it). i have some experience in android app development but not much.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the AndroidManifest.xml and on each activity add

```
        <activity
        android:name=".Example"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_example"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        />
```

Comment: `/data/user/0/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro/files/decoded/AndroidManifest.xml:25: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'horizontal').`     this error is showing at every position i am editing

Comment: Apologies it should be `landscape` i will update the answer

Comment: well i tried an app which had like 4 places to change from unspecified to landscape, but it didn't even started (crashed). another simple calculator app which didn't even had an option 'screenOrientaion'. well i am editing via an app 'apk Editor' so should i install the 'android studio' ? will this it make any diffrence ??